# Timestamp with date() throwing error that its not a timestamp

Tags: php, date

I am getting the following error from the following code.

```
$start_date = '1452953820';
$date = date($start_date,"jS M Y");
```

> Error: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

I don't understand how to sort this, as the string is a timestamp.

Any ideas?

Comment: *Any ideas?* Yup read the documentation for `date()`

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php - first argument is format and the second - timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this,,

```
$date = date("jS M Y",$start_date);// swapping arguments.
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp) for more information and more formats.